# How can svn co give a "directory already exists error"?

Tags: svn

```
svn co svn+ssh://myhost/path/projectname/trunk projectname

[...]

svn: Failed to add directory 'projectname/test/.svn': an unversioned 
  directory of the same name already exists
```

How is that possible??

I'm checking out into an empty dir.

Same error checking out to Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I may have seen this problem before when somebody had committed the .svn directory itself to the repository.  Thus, when trying to create the working directory, the versioned .svn directory couldn't be created because the working directory already had its own .svn directory.

Comment: Shouts of joy! You nailed it. All is well now.

Comment: @Ethan: since this is your solution, I'm wondering what version of SVN you're running?  SVN doesn't allow the .svn folders to be committed, except for a brief run of builds with a bug in it somewhere in the 1.5.x series, if memory serves.  You might want to upgrade to the latest.

Comment: @Ethan: Any ideas how to fix the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028908/how-can-svn-co-give-a-directory-already-exists-error

Comment: @Patrick, try doing a `svn delete` on the repository URL of the .svn directory.

Comment: I had this same issue on a folder called css and wasn't able to do svn delete (gave me an error that the file was not found). I resolved it by creating a new directory, css2, moving all files from css to css2. I then did `svn add css2` and `rm -rf css` followed by `svn update` to get rid of the ghost folder. then, AFTER checking in my changes, I did `svn mv css2 css` and committed that change to put things back normal.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, though not with a '.svn' directory, but a normal one.

I was getting this error when checking out into an empty dir:

> svn: Failed to add directory 'files': an unversioned directory of the
>   same name already exists

The directory had dynamic content and was set to svn:ignore, and the repository was possibly also corrupted.

I did a `rm -rf files` and then repeated the checkout. The checkout succeeded after that.

(though the 'files' dir became empty on the second checkout, whereas the first time it checked out some stuff into it as well. fortunately it was only dynamically generated content, so not a serious problem).

Answer (score 2):

Are you **sure** it is empty and that .svn doesn't exist? Have you tried not giving it `projectname` and instead moving into that dir and checking it out?

Answer (score 2):

If you're absolutely certain that the directory you're checking out into is empty, you may want to see if the repository contains directories with the same name using different capitalization.  This sometimes happens when the host OS for the repository is Linux.  Sometimes this causes problems when the working directory FS isn't case-sensitive.

Comment: @Ethan The default FS for OS X is _not_ case sensitive. (Unless that has changed recently)

Comment: The case sensitivity of the SVN server doesn't matter.  The SVN repo structure itself is case-sensitive on all platforms.  You only run into trouble when you've done case-insensitive things to a working copy and then committed it (i.e. from windows, or, apparently, OSX, which is news to me).

Answer (score 2):

If you've previously checked out into this directory, there could be a hidden .svn folder (folders prefixed with dot are the equivalent of hidden in Linux/OSX)?

Does the same problem occur in another recently created folder?

Answer (score 2):

My encounter with the "**failed to add directory a versioned directory XYZ... a the same name already exists**" error.

I checked out files in `/regular-folder/`:

I did not:

- changed the folder name
- add or modified any camelCase files

I just added new files and modified existing files in existing checked out folder.

*After failed attempts to clean out, I just copied the folder (with .svn) for back up, deleted the folder in system. And updated.*

Problem solved. Not sure how it was created.
One thing I learned with svn - don't do renames (files/folders) and modifications together. This was not the case.

(Windows XP, TortoiseSVN 1.6.7)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same issue because I'd updated my SVN client to a newer version and had not updated the working copy to the new format.